# Explicit type parameters in let bindings in classes (error FS0665)

Tags: .net, generics, f#

When I try to create some class like

```
type MyType () =
    let func<'T> () = ()
```

The compiler says that there's an error:

```
error FS0665: Explicit type parameters may only be used on 
              module or member bindings
```

But the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233238.aspx) says:

> A let binding at the module level, in a type, or in a computation expression can have explicit type parameters. A let binding in an expression, such as within a function definition, cannot have type parameters.

Why documentation and compiler say different things?

Comment: That `let` probably needs to be `member`.

Comment: The spec forbids it as well (by omission and more specifically in the grammar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a syntactic restriction on `let` bindings inside a class. However, you can still define a generic local function, you just have to specify the type parameters in type annotations:

```
type MyType () =
   let func (x : 'T) : 'T = x
```

I do not think this is explicitly *syntactically* forbidden by the specification, because the specification says that a class definition has the following structure:

> type type-name patopt as-defnopt =
>         class-inherits-decl<sub>opt</sub>
>         class-function-or-value-defns<sub>opt</sub>
>         type-defn-elements

and *class-or-value-defn* is defined as:

> class-function-or-value-defn := attributes<sub>opt</sub> `static`<sub>opt</sub> `let` `rec`<sub>opt</sub> function-or-value-defns

where *function-or-value-defns* may be a function definition with explicit type parameters:

> function-defn :=
>    `inline`<sub>opt</sub> `access`<sub>opt</sub> ident-or-op typar-defns<sub>opt</sub> argument-pats return-typeopt = expr

Comment: So the MSDN is wrong saying that we can have explicit type parameters inside a type?

Comment: Except when you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916321
So when the compiler decides to make a function like yours non-generic  (see linked question) I can't add explicit type parameters and have to turn my let-binding into a member (what's the exact difference again?) . I swear, I've been using F# for years now but sometimes its syntax just feels like a huge trainwreck

Answer (score 5):

To add to Tomas's answer, if you need a type parameter but won't have a value of that type you can use a type with a phantom type parameter. e.g.:

```
open System

type Foo() =
    member x.PrintType<'T> () = printfn "%s" typeof<'T>.Name

type TypeParameter<'a> = TP

let foo = Foo ()

let callFoo (typeParameter : TypeParameter<'a>) =
    foo.PrintType<'a> ()

callFoo (TP : TypeParameter<string>)
callFoo (TP : TypeParameter<DateTime>)
```

Comment: Phew so with this trick, we can implement a type-level function in a programming language that lacks typedef-in-a-type (I'm from C++)