# Parsing a string to an enum in F#

Tags: enums, f#

I am trying to do the following (which doesn't compile):

```
let Parse<'T> value =
    Enum.Parse(typedefof<'T>, value) :?> 'T
```

In short I would like to pass an enum type, and a string and get back an enum value.
An example usage would be:

```
type MyEnums =
    | Green = 0,
    | Blue = 1
```

and then:

```
let r = Parse<MyEnums> "Green"
```

what would be the syntax? I haven't used generics yet in F#, so this is what I came up with from reading the docs.

bonus question would be if there is a way to parse enums in a case insensitive way (besides turning everything to lowercase for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *does* compile for me (also without `true`, did you `open System`?):

```
let Parse<'T> value =
    System.Enum.Parse(typedefof<'T>, value, true) :?> 'T
```

and works case-insensitive for

```
type MyEnums =
    | Green = 0
    | Blue = 1

Parse<MyEnums> "Green" // Green
Parse<MyEnums> "blue" // Blue
```

Comment: I am getting:   Program.fs(50, 9): [FS0665] Explicit type parameters may only be used on module or member bindings. But now I realized something: it doesn't let me compile it inside a function. As its own function, it compiles, but when it's inside another function it will not. Why is that?

Comment: @Thomas see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396234/explicit-type-parameters-in-let-bindings-in-classes

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this in a hurry, which I believe has the advantage of not accepting other types than enums. Haven't had time to google for a better way, if there is one. Also, the underlying type must be int, and I haven't had time to see if there's something to be done with that either.

```
type MyEnum = | A = 1 | B = 2

let parseEnum<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : struct and 'T :> ValueType and 'T : enum<int>> v =
    match Enum.TryParse<'T> v with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | false, _ -> None

let x = parseEnum<MyEnum> "B"
match x with
| Some x -> printfn "%A" x
| None -> printfn "Sorry"

// let z = parseEnum<int> "1"  //  won't compile
```